# Ticks on python colorbar is missing on mac

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a weird problem which I am having a hard time solving. I am using python to plot some variables from a netcdf file. In this case precipitation. When I run the code on my mac not all ticks shows on the colorbar. However, when I run the exact same code on my linux server all ticks does show up.

The python path on my mac is:

```
~:which python  
/opt/local/bin/python
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions on what the problem could be.

Ticks are missing on MAC:

[image: Ticks are missing on mac]

Ticks are not missing on Linux:

[image: Ticks are not missing on linux]

My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os,sys
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fil = str(sys.argv[1])

nc_f = nc.Dataset(fil,'r')
lats = nc_f.variables['XLAT'][0,:,:]
lons = nc_f.variables['XLONG'][0,:,:]
precip = nc_f.variables['PREC'][:,:,:]
nc_wrf.close()

precip_lvl=[0.0,0.1,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,7.0,10.0,15.0,20.0,25.0,30.0,35.0,40.0]
precip_color = [(1.00, 1.00, 1.00), (0.84, 0.69, 0.63),
(0.72,0.56,0.51), (0.80,0.86,1.00),(0.65,0.73,1.00),(0.49,0.63,1.00),
(0.37,0.42,0.97),(0.31,0.33,0.98),(0.13,0.57,0.09),
(0.20,0.71,0.18),(0.65,0.80,0.36),(0.68,0.99,0.36),(1.0,1.0,0.08),
(0.99,0.57,0.05),(0.86,0.00,0.02),(0.68,0.00,0.02),(0.42,0.00,0.02)]


 m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=50,urcrnrlat=60,\
        llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=20,lat_ts=0,resolution='i')

x,y=m(lons,lats)
for indx in xrange(36):

    tmp = precip[indx,:,:]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    m.contourf(x,y,tmp,levels=precip_lvl, extend='both', colors=precip_color)
    plt.colorbar(shrink=0.8,ticks=precip_lvl)

    typ='.png'
    name='prec'
    plt.savefig(name+str(indx)+typ)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first compare version numbers between two machines.

```
import matplotlib
import mpl_toolkits.basemap
print(matplotlib.__version)
print(mpl_toolkits.basemap.__version__)
```

Comment: On my mac it gives me:
1.5.0, 1.0.7
and on linux:
1.3.1, 1.0.7
So the matplotlib versions are different. But could this really cause the problem?

Comment: It is very possible that some bugs in older version had been fixed in newer version.

Comment: @Whir: You might be experiencing this bug: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5673.

Comment: I solved it by updating matplotlib from 1.5.0 to 1.5.1 Unfortunately I don't know what caused the problem but at least it's working now.

Comment: When it is caused by someone else's bug and has been fixed, why bother?